# Evaluating a definite integral from $0$ to $2\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I'm stuck evaluating the following integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{\cos(t) \ |\cos(t)| \ \sqrt{\sin^2(t) + \frac{\cos^2(t)}{4}}}{\sqrt{1+3\sin^2(t)}} \ dt$$

It shouldn't be difficult, but aside from splitting the integral to get rid of absloute value, I am not seeing it correctly. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sin^2$ and $\cos^2$ are $\pi$ periodic, whereas $\cos(t+\pi)|\cos(t+\pi)|= - \cos(t)|\cos t|$. As a result, the integral from $0$ to $\pi$ is the same as the integral from $\pi$ to $2\pi$ but with opposite sign. Conclusion: the integral is zero.